# How do I define xlsxwriter formats in an external module?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

So, I'm loving xlsxwriter, and am possibly just doing something "unpythonic" in my approach, but I would like to use an external file to define my formats so that I can pull it into all my other code so that I can have consistent formats without repeatedly duplicating the format code.

As an over-simplified example, if I create a file called "table_formats.py" with these contents:

```
    def format_tables(myworkbook):
        # Create a format for a bolded title:
        myheader_format = myworkbook.add_format({
            'bold': True,
            'font_size': 14,
            'text_wrap': False
        })
```

...then, skipping a bunch of other code here, I call that add_format function from within my main program:

```
    from table_formats import *
    format_tables(myworkbook)
```

...which runs with no error, but then when I try to use the format like this:

```
    myworksheet.write(whichrow, whichcol, 'Big Data', myheader_format)
```

...it throws an error:

```
    NameError: name 'myheader_format' is not defined
```

Note: My formats work if they are in the same python file, just not if they are defined through a function in an external module. I would think this is a common design pattern but haven't found any similar questions posted. I'm fairly new to python so again there may just be something fundamentally "unpythonic" that I'm doing wrong here. Thanks for any help!

Comment: BTW, this seems to work for a single format if I explicitly return that one format, but ideally I'd like to add a dozen or more formats to each workbook that I create. Is the best way to define a dozen+ functions, one to return each format?

Answer (score 1):

Your `format_tables` function only declares a local variable that just vanishes the moment you call the function.

You can change your function to return the newly created format:

```
def format_tables(workbook):
    # Create a format for a bolded title:
    myheader_format = workbook.add_format({
        'bold': True,
        'font_size': 14,
        'text_wrap': False
    })
    return myheader_format
```

and use it in another module like:

```
from table_formats import format_tables
myheader_format = format_tables(myworkbook)
```

Comment: Thank you @Kos. That works for a single format, but ideally I'd like to add a dozen or more formats to each workbook that I create. Is the only way to define a dozen+ functions, one to return each format?

Comment: You could just write one function that creates all the formats and returns all of them in a `dict`, would that help?